# Is "of course" polite?

Tags: politeness

I read someone's journal in lang-8.com, he is asking whether "of course" is a polite enough to use because her teacher (which is american) told her "of course" is not so polite because it sounds like the answer is **a certainty and no one should not ask such that question**.

for example :

Q: Do you like that movie ?

A: Of course, I like it.

come to think of it isn't entirely wrong for me. What about you?

Comment: Whether *"**Of course**"* is "polite" or "rudely dismissive" is entirely a matter of context (and the opinions of both speaker and intended audience). So the question as framed is Unclear (it lacks sufficient context) and/or Primarily Opinion-based. But that's just my own opinion, of course.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mean it's really depends on the interlocutors, condition, and the context? I added example to my question, how about that? Also do you use "of course" often to anyone such as parents, teachers, etc in general context? I mean not in angry situation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course you are right on the main point, and should post that as an answer. But to my mind the opinion bit is a red herring - replace "What about you?" with "Is this a valid rule?" and we're just fine - and the unclarity is **of course** precisely what OP is asking about.

Comment: @StoneyB: I retracted my closevote following the "clarifying edit". But I can't really agree with your "the opinion bit is a red herring". Specifically, the last two words in my previous comment could be seen as "sarcastically dismissive" (they often are when people say *"Of course, that's just my opinion"* in contexts where their opinion might be seen as overridingly important). Or they might be submissively underplaying the significance of my comments. Or again, they might have been an effectively meaningless echo of the term under consideration (which is probably nearer the truth! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps we need a third site: ELU, ELL and ME--MetaEnglish! ... Of course that would land all the really interesting questions in Meta.MetaEnglish, where **all** questions would be opinion-based.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think quite possibly my *favourite* questions on ELL/ELU are the ones where I initially think *"X, of course"*, but end up thinking *"**Y**, of course"*. I recall recently reading some theoretical physicist saying the goal of everyone in his field was to come out with something totally new that would make everyone say *"**Why** of course! How could it ever have been otherwise?"*. The problem with "MetaEnglish" would be there'd *always* be at least some people who thought otherwise, no matter how much the issue was discussed and dissected.

Comment: btw - the reason I haven't actually posted an answer is I don't have a clear understanding of the range of possible contexts that ***of course*** could be used in. Just saying "it's all a matter of context" doesn't seem very useful. Ideally I'd like to see an answer arranging the more likely contexts into coherent "groups", which might then make it obvious there are actually only a relatively small number of "basic" contexts (with their inevitable variations). Maybe a Community Wiki answer is the way to go here.

Comment: This question needs information about intonation and solidarity - _how_ these are said and _what the relationship_ between the speakers is - as well as some co-text - more dialogue before and after the part in question. Out of context, you just can't say anything definitively. If they'd been talking about how *Q* always drags *A* to movies without asking *A*'s opinion, this could be both rude and sarcastic.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't provide more about the context,etc because that is all that I got from someone's jurnal in lang-8 and made curious too to ask. but I think I already got the point you all talked above.. thanks all ;)

Comment: Here's a video we made about this very question. Perhaps it will help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL-5xb_OkDo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locution "of course" is neither polite nor impolite.  The tone in which it is delivered makes all the difference.

```
Did you like the movie about swashbuckling pirates?
--Of course, I liked it, matey! You know how much I like to talk like a pirate, arrrh!

Would you like to come with us to the concert? I know your car is in the shop.
--Of course, it's so nice of you to offer.


Do you like those cookies I baked for you?
-- Of course I like them, it's *my* recipe after all! Why wouldn't I like them?
```

Comment: +1 Of course there's also concessive *of course*. And perhaps a depressive *of course*: "Of course it did; that's what always happens to me"

Comment: There's probably also the repressive *of course*.  *Of course, you're not going to stage a popular rebellion, are you?* And an obsessive *of course".  "Of course, you're going to wash that apple before eating it, aren't you? Well, aren't you??!"